# How to Handle Date Picker in Selenium and Appium Test cases in android

Tags: android, selenium, appium, testcase

Please I am new tester in Appium.So please suggest me How to Handle Date Picker test cases in Appium using AndroidDriver And Selenium

Thanks.

Comment: Custom Component will be more useful.

Comment: share the ui of the picker